# How to get date row difference in SQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this below

table1

```
id  date    
--------------------
12  20-04-2019 12:35
2   20-04-2019 12:55
11  20-04-2019 11:57
7   20-04-2019 12:00
5   20-04-2019 12:05
```

and I want  to get like below

```
id  date                diff
----------------------------------------
12  20-04-2019 12:35    0
2   20-04-2019 12:55    20-04-2019 00:20
11  20-04-2019 11:57    20-04-2019 00:20
7   20-04-2019 12:00    20-04-2019 00:03
5   20-04-2019 12:05    20-04-2019 00:05
```

Please help me.

Comment: I don't get the logic for the calculation.

Comment: Typo for the second `20-04-2019 00:20` ?

Comment: use LAG window function to get previous row and then DIFF(mm, date, LAG....) + format

Answer (score 1):

Please find the demo with the sample data for your scenario:

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE (Id INT, DateValue DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @TestTable (Id, DateValue) VALUES
(12 , '04-20-2019 12:35'),
(2  , '04-20-2019 12:55'),
(11 , '04-20-2019 11:57'),
(7  , '04-20-2019 12:00'),
(5  , '04-20-2019 12:05');

SELECT Id, 
       DateValue,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, LAG(DateValue) OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)), DateValue), 0), 114) AS Diff
FROM @TestTable;
```

Output:

```
Id  DateValue                 Diff
------------------------------------
12  2019-04-20 12:35:00.000   NULL
2   2019-04-20 12:55:00.000   00:20
11  2019-04-20 11:57:00.000   23:02
7   2019-04-20 12:00:00.000   00:03
5   2019-04-20 12:05:00.000   00:05
```

Comment: getting below error while executing above query please help me   ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR(5), DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, LAG(DateValue) OVER (ORDER' at line 1

Comment: I see you are tagged with SQL-Server.  MySQL is different than SQL Server